# Is there suffering in the Bastard's hell?

Tags: lois-mcmaster-bujold, chalion

In Lois McMaster Bujold's Chalion series (The Curse of Chalion, Paladin of Souls and The Hallowed Hunt), the Quintarian religion plays a pivotal role. There are five gods: the  Father, the Mother, the Son, the Daugher and the Bastard.

Upon death, the soul of the deceased is usually taken up by one of the gods. The afterlife for those that are taken by the Father, Mother, Son or Daughter isn't described further, but for the Bastard it is mentioned at several points in the books that he takes the souls to his Hell.

With the word Hell we usually associate (eternal) suffering, but the reaction from the characters in the book don't really seem to fit with that idea of hell. They seem more embarrased if the Bastard takes up a soul, not distraught as expected if they thought that the deceased was suffering in Hell.

Are there any further details known on what kind of place the Bastard's Hell is, and how it differs from the afterlife with any of the other gods?

Answer (score 3):

When a god takes up a soul, even if it's the Bastard, it goes to heaven. 
Only the Bastard's demons take souls to hell and this usually only happens during a deathmagic ritual where the performer of the ritual makes some sacrifices (a rat and a crow) and prays to the Bastard to take the victim's soul. If the target is deserving of the Bastard's vengeance then the demon is summoned, the price for this is that the Bastard's demon also takes the summoner's soul.

During a funeral one of the sacred animals (each one representing a specific god, (a rat for the bastard) is brought to the body by an acolyte of each god in turn and it is this animal that shows the people at the funeral which god had claimed the soul.

Each of the gods takes specific people.

The Father takes fathers, the Mother takes mothers. The Daughter takes childless women, girls and soldiers of her order, the Son takes childless men, boys and soldiers of his order. The Bastard takes everyone else and also homosexuals, even if the homosexuals are eligible to be chosen by the other gods. This choosing at a funeral, even if it's the Bastard, is recognition of the soul being claimed by a god and entry into heaven.

The Bastard's hell meanwhile looks like this:

> Ista had a vision of a strange, dimensionless void, the picture leaked, perhaps, from His mind to hers: a roiling pool of demon energy, without form, without personas, without minds or wills or song or speech or memories or any gift of higher order—the Bastard’s hell. Reservoir of pure destruction. Spilling from that pool into the world of matter, a thin controlled flow. Returning to it, an erratic stream. Balancing the life of the world exactly midway between the hot death that is chaos and the chill death that is stasis. She realized at last why the concatenation of Joen’s demons had made her edgy, on a level separate from their direct threat to Porifors. Was it possible that such a vortex of disorder might create its own rip between the two realms, one that even the gods might be hard-pressed to mend again? So much divine attention in one small place …

This is from *The Paladin of Souls*, the second Chalion book.

Comment: The excerpt from the second book is interesting. +1

Comment: @coleopterist. Excellent edit, thank you

Comment: Note that it's not clear that the death demon takes the _summoner's_ soul to the Bastard's Hell; we don't have any information what happened to the soul of the merchant in _Curse_, but we do hear that the Father takes up Martou dy Jironal's soul (which was the substitute for dy Cazaril's), so we know only Dondo (the target) went to Hell.

Answer (score 2):

From Chapter 17 of *The Curse of Chalion*:

> What must it be like, to feel one’s very spirit slowly rot away around one, as flesh rotted from dead limbs? Did the ghosts sense their own diminishment, or did that self-perception, too, mercifully, wear away in time? **The Bastard’s legendary hell, with all its supposed torments, seemed a sort of heaven by comparison.**

Chapter 13 has *Umegat* talking about The Bastard's demons:

> “Likewise, should the miracle cease that you presently host—should the Lady’s hand lift,” Umegat mimed someone opening their hands as if to release a bird, “I think the demon would immediately attempt to complete its destiny. Not that it has a choice—the Bastard’s demons have no free will. You can’t argue with or persuade them. In fact, there’s no use talking to one at all.”

Going by the above, the Quintarian hell does not sound like a pleasant place. Incidentally, when I read the first quoted passage, I wondered how lost and abandoned souls are addressed by the Quadrenes.